# Calling a method at a specific time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, methods, time

I've created a recorder that stores the CFAbsoluteTime of a triggered sound and the name of it in two separate arrays. In order to play the recording back, I need a time-accurate way of calling the trigger sound method. Preferably it should be non-processor intensive; I did something a while back that worked accurately but hogged all of the iphone's memory.

For example, I've tried NSTimer which seems to lag a bit with non-exact playback, and NSThread which was memory intensive.

What are some of my options, with pros and cons? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you think about doing something like this:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(playSound) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];
```

Comment: It worked out great! Using this I was able to queue up all of the sounds in the array and they play back with no noticeable lag. Definitely the right way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Check the `dispatch_later` documentation. It is more flexible and guaranteed to run in the estimated time than using performSelector:afterDelay;